# How to Hide Drupal Site from Google?

Tags: search, drupal, googlebot, nofollow

I have a website, and I use Drupal for CMS. i.e. I write articles in `mysite.com/drupal/` but I display them in `mysite.com/show_article.php?article_id=x&article_name=y` (actually `mysite.com/article/x/y` with .htaccess RewriteRule) by loading the content from Drupal database.

However, when I search for an article in google, `mysite.com/drupal/node/x/y` appears as the result, but `mysite.com/article/x/y` doesn't.

so I guess I need to add some `<google nofollow>` tags in drupal's php pages, but which ones? or is there an easier configuration setting for this?

Thanks !

Comment: You may want to use a robots.txt file to start with

Comment: You might want to set the rewritten path as the `$base_url` in settings.php as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

robots.txt:

```
User-agent: *
disallow: /drupal/
```

Then you'll want to submit an index for mysite.com/article to Google. It sounds like you won't be able to use [XML sitemap](http://dgo.to/xmlsitemap) for this however.

That should be all you need to do what you need. Of course the obvious question (if I understand what you're doing) is why you're using custom php to serve up Drupal content from the same domain, and not just doing this in Drupal.

Comment: Thank you very much! As for why I'm trying to do this is, first, I already have a website design which I want to use instead of Drupal's design. And second, I want to display ads on the page. So I decided not to mess with drupal's core, and use it as a practical content editor.